# Stretching body CSS

Tags: css

I want the Body to be the full height of page all times. With and without content.

Some of my code:

````
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-left: 3px solid #6a6a6a;
    border-right: 3px solid #6a6a6a;
}

html {
    font-family: kiona;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    height: 100%;
} ```
````

Comment: You could use `min-height: 100vh`. It means, "make the height 100% of the vertical height of the viewport"

Comment: @TannerDolby at least*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply this style to your body:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This means, that your body height will be **at least** set to the **100%** of the **viewport height**.

Comment: @dmarinus04 that should work. Check it in the dev tools.

Comment: @dmarinus04 provide minimal snippet. It should work but depends on the situation.